# Combine Two Commands (Get Video from Images)

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have 300 images and i wants to generate video from these images. 
i am new to FFMPEG so now i am using two commands to generate video from images. 
Command to generate video from images which also add Logo on video

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img_%d.jpg -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" \
-vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p  test_video.mp4
```

After using above command i am getting the video to add audio to this video i am using below command

```
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -i inputfile.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a libvorbis -shortest final_video.mp4
```

which generates video and i am getting below message

```
MPEG-4 AAC decoder is required to play the file
```

Help to combine this both command. if possible can we add sound without any decoder required

Log for command 1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zS7gvrPy69VK_MkyE4127FpX2kEziJHq/view?usp=sharing

and Log command 2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rHqVGzj7f003aWP6eISiyUjsES8_EWuw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Share full log for both your commands.

Comment: @Gyan Added log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img_%d.jpg -i logo.png -i inputfile.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" \
-vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -map 2:a -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest test_video.mp4
```

`-map 2:a` is needed to skip image in case if there is cover image in track.
With `-c:a copy` track will not be re-encoded, so you will have mp3 inside of your video file.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ there was nothing in question about making it work on android. 
Try to search about errors that you have. And if there is no success, create an issue on Stack Overflow.

Comment: log [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZEjcumY9qUACHvOSdW-3FxMQ66Gr7t4/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZEjcumY9qUACHvOSdW-3FxMQ66Gr7t4/view?usp=sharing)